# Why does Kate risk all her bodies?

Tags: invincible

In the streaming version of *Invincible*, Kate Cha (Dupli-Kate) is capable of creating copies of herself that share a single mind. She typically uses this power in combat by arriving to a fight in a single body (her "prime" self) and then splitting off additional bodies as needed. This means that all her bodies are typically involved in a single fight.

However, this obviously carries the substantial risk of all her bodies being destroyed. Why does Kate use all her bodies in battle, instead of splitting beforehand and keeping one or two a safe distance away?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

She doesn't risk *all* her bodies. Spoilers ahead - this answer is based off the comics.

In Issue 40 what you describe in your question unfortunately does happen. Dupli-Kate and her copies are killed when the Lizard League attacks the Guardians of the Globe's HQ.

However, a few issues later (Issue 46) The Immortal comes home to find an alive and well Kate in his living room. She explains that she always lives through a copy and has kept this a secret from everyone. As per her brother Paul she "*hid her zero to only live through her one*":

[image: A panel showing Dupli-Kate. The relevant text is quoted below]

> I had a close call once -- decided then and there **I'd always live life through a copy, never leaving myself exposed**. All my copies share the same consciousness, all part of the same person -- it's hard to explain.

[image: A panel showing Multi-Paul. The text is quoted below]

> I didn't know if you'd taken my advice and **hidden your zero to only live through your one**... I'd hoped you had, but so much time had passed after your death...

Comment: It will be interesting to see what happens in the streaming version in this case.  But it does  raise the question.  Where does her "zero" live, and what does she do while the rest of her is out fighting bad guys?  I see mention of her "sanctuary", but no idea what this actually is.

Comment: @PeterM in the first screenshot she says it took time to get out of her sanctuary. I can’t recall offhand if it’s ever mentioned again

Comment: I saw that.  (I was editing my comment at the same time you were writing yours)

Comment: Looks like the animated version has caught up with issue 40 (and prompted this question) but not yet through issue 46... The question remains of why none of her teammates ever talked to her about this before if they didn't know. Especially Robot who tends to think these things through.

Comment: @Stef If characters in shows did the logical/smart thing, then the duration of the entertainment would be a lot shorter.  So much plot is built up on "manufactured drama" /s

Comment: @Stef - Robot, in fact, seems to have a very similar problem, which I asked about in another question a few days ago.